# How to setup and use a GitHub framework in Xcode without CocoaPods

Tags: xcode, github, swiftycam

I am trying to add in various github frameworks into my app. I am new to this and I am not sure exactly how to do this.
For example if I want to add the following from github https://github.com/Awalz/SwiftyCam
I do not want to use CocoaPods and I simply follow the section for manual, how do I incorporate this into my app and actually get using the camera.

So far I have dragged in the files from the source section and placed it into my Xcode project.

[image]

[image]

Now I have created a new viewcontroller in storyboard and made it fit to the custom class of swiftycam.

Here is where I get confused as to how I proceed, and I am not sure if I have done everything up to here correct.

If someone with experience in this can show a step-by-step it will be greatly appreciated for this and all future GitHub frameworks I wish to add.

Thank you!